# Rails-4.2 Share view with muliple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a model called Authorisation that is a join table for User and Role.  When looked at from the User point of view (POV) then an Authorisation is called an Endorsement.  When looked at from the Role POV it is called a Holder.  These are implemented using nested resources:

```
  resources( :users ) do
    resources(  :roles,
      :as => 'endorsements',
      :controller => 'endorsements' )
  end

  resources( :roles ) do
    resources( :users,
      :as => 'holders',
      :controller => 'holders' )
  end
```

We need to maintain Authorisations directly.  But we also need to maintain them for specific Users or Roles.  We have created three controllers named, authorisations_controller.rb, endorsements_controller.rb and holders_controller.rb.  We would like all three to use the same views/authorisations/new|edit|show|index pages since other than the filter of User or Role these are identical in nature.

However, when we enter the views/authorisations/new.html.erb template from endorsements_controller.rb the submit button causes program control to return to the authorisations_controller rather than the calling endorsements_controller.  Is there a Rails-4 idiom to allow views to be shared among controllers and return to the calling instance?

Comment: You can pass a `ret` param in the url to use to return to. The other options is setting it in the session. You can also check the type of user you are authenticating and redirect based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `EndorsementSController` you can either:
use `redirect_to` and set the return to path and desired flash message,
or use the `responders` gem, which takes a `location` argument.
I.e. `respond_with user, location: endorsements_path`

More info about `responders` is available at:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to
- https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

Comment: I worked around this by using a soft link from `./views/endorsements/new.html.erb` to `./views/authorisations/new.html.erb`.   However, the suggested _responders_ gem approach appears more robust.